# Call Spring Scheduler execution from Java code

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I have this simple example of Spring Scheduler:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AppScheduler {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void myScheduler() {
        System.out.println("Test print");
    }

}
```

Is there a way to trigger execution in the current moment let's say from web page?

Comment: `myScheduler()` is just a java method like any other method.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a dump controller to call `myScheduler` method:

```
@Controller
public class DumpController {
     @Autowired
     private AppScheduler scheduler;

     @RequestMapping("/ping")
     public void ping() {
         scheduler.myScheduler();
     }
}
```